# How to make @SpringBootTest use configurable properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I make Spring create an application context using a specific properties file made for testing purposes when using @SpringBootTest rather than using the standard application.properties?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53169935/springboottest-is-connecting-to-database/53170116#53170116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an `application.properties` file (or YAML variant) under `src/test/resources`.

---

Alternatively, you can define properties for test in the [`@TestPropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) annotation:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(
        properties = {
                "foo.bar: value",
                "fiz.biz: value"
        })
public class FooTest {
    ...
}
```

This approach is equivalent to defining the properties the [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) annotation:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        properties = {
                "foo.bar: value",
                "fiz.biz: value"
        })
public class FooTest {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first way suggested works for me but the second one doesn't for some reason.